# Parse a structured flattened json object to list of object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am current have a Json like :

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "gatewayId":"asd",
      "records":[  
         {  
            "ms":123,
            "points":[  
               {  
                  "sensorId":"asdasd",
                  "sensorType":"asdasd",
                  "batt" : 12,
                  "kw" : 2
               },
               {  
                  "sensorId":"123",
                  "sensorType":"as123dasd",
                  "batt" : 12,
                  "kw" : 2
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "ms":123123,
            "points":[  
               {  
                  "sensorId":"asdasd",
                  "sensorType":"asdasd",
                  "batt" : 12,
                  "kw" : 2
               },
               {  
                  "sensorId":"123",
                  "sensorType":"as123dasd",
                  "batt" : 12,
                  "kw" : 2
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
  "gatewayType":"Asdasd"
}
```

My purpose is to denormalise the object to the lowest level in Java

where the pojo is

```
class SimpleData {
private String gatewayId;
private String gatewayType;
private Long ms;
private String sensorType;
private Double batt;
private Long kw;
}
```

For what I did for now, I flatten the json to a list for string as below.

```
root.gatewayType="Asdasd"
root.data.gatewayId="asd"
root.data.records[0].ms=123
root.data.records[0].points[0].sensorId="asdasd"
root.data.records[0].points[0].sensorType="asdasd"
root.data.records[0].points[0].batt=12
root.data.records[0].points[0].kw=2
root.data.records[0].points[1].sensorId="123"
root.data.records[0].points[1].sensorType="as123dasd"
root.data.records[0].points[1].batt=12
root.data.records[0].points[1].kw=2
root.data.records[1].ms=123123
root.data.records[1].points[0].sensorId="asdasd"
root.data.records[1].points[0].sensorType="asdasd"
root.data.records[1].points[0].batt=12
root.data.records[1].points[0].kw=2
root.data.records[1].points[1].sensorId="123"
root.data.records[1].points[1].sensorType="as123dasd"
root.data.records[1].points[1].batt=12
root.data.records[1].points[1].kw=2
```

I am thinking is it any logic or library can parse the above list for string to list of SimpleData object?

---

Sorry, My question maybe not clear, I find a more simple way to solve the problem.
But I need a library to denormalize the json.

for example if the json is :

```
{
"a" : "1",
"b" : ["2", "3"]
}
```

will become

```
[
{
"a" : "1",
"b" : "2"
},
{
"a" : "1",
"b" : "3"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library is what you are looking for. It provides simple methods to convert Json array to simple Java objects, and vice versa. Very handy, developed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [fastjson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson), which is really fast and quite easy to use. In your case, you only need to define POJO in the structure as your JSON data and parse the JSON to Object. It's created by Alibaba.